# Empty keys when generating JSON Web Key Set (JWKS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, jwk, jose

I'm trying to create a JSON web key set for use with a node.js API client. However when logging my keys they seem to be empty.

```
const {JWKS} = require("jose");
const keyAlg = "RSA";
const keySize = 2048;
const keyUse = "sig";
const alg = "RS256";
const keystore = new JWKS.KeyStore();
keystore.generate(keyAlg, keySize, {
  alg,
  use: keyUse,
});

console.log("Public keys");
console.log("This can be used as the jwks in your API client configuration in the portal");
console.log(JSON.stringify(keystore.toJWKS(), null, 4));
console.log("Private keys");
console.log("This can be used as the keys value when configuring the api client");
console.log(JSON.stringify(keystore.toJWKS(true), null, 4));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keystore.generate` is an asynchronous function. It returns a promise which won't be executed immediately. You can use `.then` or async/await to get the results of a promise.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose#managing-keys) from the libraries github:

> keystore.generate("oct", 256).
> then(function(result) {
> // {result} is a jose.JWK.Key
> key = result;
> });

Applying this to your code:

```
const {JWKS} = require("jose");
const keyAlg = "RSA";
const keySize = 2048;
const keyUse = "sig";
const alg = "RS256";
const keystore = new JWKS.KeyStore();
keystore.generate(keyAlg, keySize, {
  alg,
  use: keyUse,
}).then(function(result) {
  
  console.log(result);
  console.log("Public keys");
  console.log("This can be used as the jwks in your API client configuration in the portal");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(keystore.toJWKS(), null, 4));
  console.log("Private keys");
  console.log("This can be used as the keys value when configuring the api client");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(keystore.toJWKS(true), null, 4));
});
```

---

If you are new to javascript asynchronous functions, take a look at the most popular question and answer on the topic:
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)